# Dynamic assignment of property names based on array values

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, properties

I am trying to create a class that is going to generate dynamic class properties according to a user input.
There will be an array created from user input data. This array should work as an example:

```
$array = array(
    # The boolean values are not relevant in this example
    # The keys are important

    'apple' => true,
    'orange' => false,
    'pear' => false,
    'banana' => true,
);
```

Right now I want to create a new class with the array keys as the class properties:

```
class Fruit {
    public $apple;
    public $orange;
    public $pear;
    public $banana;

(etc.)
}
```

I had to manually write down all four properties now.
Is there a way to make it automated?

Comment: Sure, php is a weak typed language. That specifically means you can implement a class without any properties but still assign any properties you like :-) So you can implement a method `setProperties()` or similar doing that, even for an array of arguments.

Comment: The answer shows how to do it with your own class, but if you just want a generic object: `$fruit = (object)$array;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

class MyClass 
{
    public function __construct ($config = []) 
    {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass(['apple' => 1, 'orange' => 2]);

echo $myClass->apple;
?>
```

this should help you

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

I put a few bonus things in there:

```
class MyClass implements Countable, IteratorAggregate
{
    protected $data = [];

    public function __construct (array $data = []) 
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __set($key, $value){
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if(!isset($this->{$key})) return null; //you could also throw an exception here.
        return $this->data[$key];
    }

    public function __isset($key){
        return isset($this->data[$key]);
    }

    public function __unset($key){
        unset($this->data[$key]);
    }

    public function __call($method, $args){

        $mode = substr($method, 0, 3);
        $property = strtolower(substr($method, 3)); //only lowercase properties
        if(isset($this->{$property})) {
            if($mode == 'set'){
                $this->{$property} = $args[0];
                return null;
            }else if($mode == 'get'){
                return $this->{$property};
            }
        }else{
            return null; //or throw an exception/remove this return
        }
        throw new Exception('Call to undefined method '.__CLASS__.'::'.$method);
    }

    //implement Countable
    public function count(){
        return count($this->data);
    }

    //implementIteratorAggregate
    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->data);
    }

}
```

Test it:

```
$myClass = new MyClass(['one' => 1, 'two' => 2]);

echo $myClass->two."\n";

//Countable
echo count($myClass)."\n";

//dynamic set
$myClass->three = 3;

echo count($myClass)."\n";

//dynamic get/set methods. I like camel case methods, and lowercase properties. If you don't like that then you can change it.
$myClass->setThree(4);
echo $myClass->getThree()."\n";

//IteratorAggregate
foreach($myClass as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.' => '.$value."\n";
}
```

Outputs

```
2 //value of 2
2 //count of $data
3 //count of $data after adding item
4 //value of 3 after changing it with setThree
//foreach output
one => 1
two => 2
three => 4
```

[Test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7096495782ae0d378fd4d5395129c9792a29f8a0)

*Disclamer*

Generally though it's better to define the class by hand, that way things like IDE's work.  You may also have issues because you won't necessarily know what is defined in the class ahead of time.  You don't have a concrete definition of the class as it were.

Pretty much any method(at least in my code) that starts with `__` is a PHP magic method (yes, that's a thing).  When I first learned how to use these I thought it was pretty cool, but now I almost never use them...

Now if you want to create an actual .php file with that code in it, that's a different conversation. (it wasn't 100% clear, if you wanted functionality or an actual file)

Cheers.